# How Can I add Custom javascript file in my laravel project?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Can anyone please guide me regarding how can I add custom javascript in Laravel project?

I did google and found some steps but unable to figure out what the error is going on?

Steps I

1. Created a custom.js in my public folder with a simple function
2. add script tag in my `app.blade.php`
3. extends my layout

But the function is not working

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert("hello this is test");
})
```

**custom.js**

```
enter code here

<script type="text/javascrip" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/custom.js')}}"></script>
```

code I added in my main file `app.blade`

but when load my page it doesn't give me an alert. Alert is just for testing I tried with various function.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the source code from the web browser?

Comment: First of all thanks chusky for showing interest but yes I did and its showing but nothing working and one more thing If I am making a simple function without $document.ready like function check(){alert("example") and call it via on click function its working but when i use it by $(document).ready(function(){}) its not working

Comment: @SamirParuthi Hello, Can you check your browser console? If any error occurred. please shared with us.

Comment: What error  are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

1. You misspelled **javascript**
2. Remove the **(")** after writing the `</script>`

---

**For Javascript:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>
```

Make your directory structure is like this for JS: `/public/js/custom.js`

Answer (score 0):

I have to review your code. I have found an error in your code like a spelling mistake.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"
```

You have miss `t` at the end of `javascript`.

Comment: @SamirParuthi When use `$(document).ready(function()`  you need to load  `jquery.min.js` But wrong spelling privent load your js file.

Comment: @SamirParuthi Happy that I can solve your issue. please accept answer.